# dynamic changing of element's css class with angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have this form:

```
<td ng-init="workflow.isSaved = false">
    <select ng-init="workflow.ProjectID = projectList[0]['Id']" chosen data-placeholder="Choose a project..."                 ng-model="workflow.ProjectID" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="workflow.isSaved = false" ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in projectList" style="width: 98%">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</td>
<td><input class="date-input" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" ng-model="workflow.Date" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="workflow.isSaved = false" datapicker /></td>
<td><input class="task-input" type="text" value="" ng-model="workflow.TaskDescription" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="workflow.isSaved = false" placeholder="Task" required /></td>
<td><input class="time-input" type="text" value="" ng-model="workflow.TimeWorked" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="workflow.isSaved = false" placeholder="Elapsed time" required /></td>
<td>
    <input class="note-input" ng-class="{'note-input-two': logform.$valid && workflow.isSaved == false}" type="text" value="" ng-model="workflow.Note" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="workflow.isSaved = false" placeholder="Note" />
    <button class="deactive-button" ng-class="{'active-accept-button' : logform.$valid && workflow.isSaved == false}" ng-click="saveTask(workflow, logform)">✔</button>
    <button class="deactive-button" ng-class="{'active-delete-button' : some_expression }" ng-click="clearRow(workflow)">✖</button>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.deactive-button {
    display: none;
}

.active-accept-button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 12%;
}

.active-delete-button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 12%;
}

.note-input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 98%;
}

.note-input-one {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85%;
}

.note-input-two {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
}
```

My task is: When I load page I can see my row without any buttons, after I changed some field of row I can see `X` button and if I filled all fiedls and myform.$valid == true I can see two buttons `V` and `X`. When I click `V` (save row data to db) I can see row with 1 button `X`. My note-input field have 3 states:
1 - `default : width: 98%;
2 - note-input-one: width: 85%;
3 - note-input-two: width: 70%;

and my buttons have 2 states;
1 - deactive-button: display: none;
2 - active-accept-button/active-delete-button: display: inline-block...

How I can realize this via angularjs. I tried to use ng-class, but it works wrong. Please, help me to solve this issue.

Comment: The natural way to go is ngClass, whats the behaviour you get with ngClass? Did you try ng-if if you want to hide/show a component it could help?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ngClass`:

```
<div ng-class="{'the-class-you-want-to-apply': theCondition === true}"></div>
```

This will add a class to the element when an expression evaluates to true. For classes that is one word, `active` for example you don't need to use the single quotes around the class name.

Using this method you can get the desired effect.